# 'Minimal σ-field' in probability

Tags: probability-theory, field-theory

I'm new to the subject and there's something I'm not so sure of.

I do think I understand what 'σ-field' is, but then I ran into 'minimal σ-field'.

Suppose that one gets $500 if heads in coin flipping. If the coin is tossed twice, then the Sample Space would be Ω={0,500,100}.

If I'm understanding the concept of σ-field correctly, the Power Set is a σ-field, and the subsets of the Power Set that satisfies the conditions are also σ-field.

Then would {∅,P(S)} be the 'minimal σ-field' or does this term have some kind of another definition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some collection of sigma fields $\sigma_i$ then $\cap \sigma_i$ is a sigma field.

If you have some sets $S_j \subset \Omega$ then the minimal sigma field containing $S_j$ is $\cap \sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i$ contains all $S_j$.